# Interface between csh and fortran code

Tags: variables, fortran, csh

I have a script (csh) which calls a fortran executable.
Each time the script calls the fortran code a counter should be incremented and using that counter I have to create a new output file.

Can I pass a variable to my fortran code or is there a simple way of doing the same.

I have tried this code:

```
 program callsave  
c  
 implicit none  
       integer i,j  
c  
do j = 1, 10  
  call trysave(i)  
  print *, i  
end do  
stop  
end  
c  
subroutine trysave(i)  
       integer k  
       data k /1/  
       save k  
       i = k  
       k = k + 1  
           end subroutine  
c
```

This works fine individually. But when I call this subroutine separately in my fortran code through the script, it is not getting incremented. It just has the initial value '1', and the output files been overwritten.

Any type of help/suggestion would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks
Praveen.

Answer (score 3):

Is it that you're looking for a way of passing an integer value from the shell script to the fortran code?
In that case, one way would be to use command line arguments, see e.g. here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/GETARG.html

I'm not sure what is the official status of the `getarg()` routine, but by experience it works fine in gfortran, intel and PGI compilers.

Comment: Fortran 2003 introduced a standard version of this subroutine, called `get_command_argument(number [, value, length, status])`.

Comment: @eriktous: thanks, it's good to know. Just out of curiousity: Are you aware of a compiler which does not support the getarg() version?

Comment: No, as I only have experience with gfortran. However, history teaches us that large amounts of fortran source code far outlive the compilers they were originally developed on, sometimes even by decades. Due to the attention to backward compatibility by the standards committee, programs which conform to the standard are usually much easier to maintain than ones that make use of extensions.